# Combinations of AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

I have an array of around 75,000 rows. For each row, a calculation needs to be done (python script) which takes about an hour and will then produce about 1GB of data.

The calculation must be run 10 times against each row using different parameters so in total it will be run 750,000 times. In no rush for the result or how long it takes to complete.

My question is what combination of AWS services can be used to effectively solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1hr exceeds the limits of Lambda. You'll need to create your own processing service, and run it on a container host like EC2.

The processing service will need to be stateful (eg the 'cursor' which marks what data has been processed already), and I suggest storing that state  off-instance - for example in DynamoDB. This will make it easier to run multiple instances in parallel, and will aid in recovering from crashes or downtime.

Storing the input data is pretty straightforward and any database could work. You may want to consider a service like Athena or Redshift over DynamoDB if you'll need to run any kind of analysis on the data later on. S3 is a fine option as well.

Your output data is large, so I suggest storing it in S3.

Putting it all together:

```
Athena -> Processor Service -> S3
```